# Is there are a hotkey for "forward delete current word" on Mac, or a way to implement it?

Tags: macos, hotkeys

I frequently use <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> for delete current word, and also <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> for forward delete, but I'm wondering if anybody has ever implemented a combination?  It would delete from your current cursor until the end of the word.  I'm only aware of <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> for deleting the rest of the line.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>option</kbd><kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd>

should do it.

Comment: You may need to mention which application you're using. It works fine in the edit box here in Safari, for example.